# Switch Statements with Variable Case?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to figure out a more elegant way to handle user input for a small program I'm working on. Nothing is broken, and I know how I *could* handle it, but it involves reusing lots of code and what I think are potentially unnecessary separate functions.

I am asking the user for input that alters what can be given for input. So on the first pass, there is just one option. On the second pass, there are 4 options. The next pass could be 4 options or 7 options. Etc.

So if I say:

```
case ConsoleKey.D1:
    function1();
    break;
case ConsoleKey.D2:
    function2();
    break;
```

Then by pressing 1, I am always going to call function 1. But I won't always need to have function 1 available as an option. But I also don't want to have the options for the user with gaps in between, them, like:

```
(1) call func1()
(2) call func2()
(5) call func5()
(8) call func8()
```

I'd rather have the input in order and assigned a function based on what functions are needed, like:

```
(1) call func1()
(2) call func4()
(3) call func6()
(4) call func9()
```

Does this make sense? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but I'll give it a go. If the same input in different parts of the program leads to a different behavior, maybe you should focus on branching these behaviors in different classes instead of relying solely on user input for the strategy. Basically, the program flow determines the behavior to be implemented, each behavior adapts the input for the strategy.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents.

```
public interface IControlBehavior {
     void Activate(int input);
}

public class FirstPhase : IControlBehavior {
    void Activate(int input) {
       //call function1 with 1, function 2 with 2...
    }
}

public class SecondPhase : IControlBehavior {
    void Activate(int input) {
      //call function1 with 1, function 5 with 2...
    }
}
```

You could even make sure that the input is correct for each phase. 
Rule of thumb is that whenever you want to refactor a switch you should think "inheritance"!

Comment: I like this implementation a lot, but the idea of creating a separate class or function for each set of circumstances seems like it could quickly get unmanageable; already I would need to have five individual cases. Lots of re-writing the same code in different places, too.

Comment: I'm not sure about re-writing the same code. If they're separate cases they should be treated seperately. The alternative would be to build 5 adapter classes that take the input and "adapt" it to your final switch case. So if you input "2" in the SecondPhase it becomes "5". Then you can call the switch in your Question with that. It can become a bit harder to read and understand but you'd have only one final switch.